# SELECTLIST not preselect the value define

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why is `DropDownListFor` item not pre-selected, although the `Model.Status` has value?

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
  model => model.Status, 
  new SelectList(
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["status"],
    "Value",
    "Text",
    (Model== null) ? "" : Model.Status),
  "")
```

**Controller**

```
ViewData["status"] = _Helper.AssignStatus("status");
```

**Class**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AssignStatus(string _GroupCd)
{
  var result = from m in db.CommonComboes
               where m.GroupCd == _GroupCd
               select new SelectListItem
               {
                 Value = m.Value,
                 Text = m.Text
               };

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you try changing ViewData["status"] to something else? I think the 'status' will interfere with the model.Status property, try ViewData["selectedStatusId"] instead

Comment: awww, cant believe it really caused the problem here, thanks, I mark your answer as correct answer, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ViewData["status"]` to something else.

I think the 'status' will interfere with the model.Status property, try   `ViewData["selectedStatusId"]` instead